# Is there any way to change background image color in JavaFX ImageView?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I have ScrollPane which has ImageView within it. When I set an image to ImageView, I get this:

[image: white rectangle on the bottom of the ImageView]

When I add an image with higher height:

[image: that's fine with the image]

Is there any way to change the color of that rectangle? (ImageView background color)

Comment: Maybe, someone knows any other ways to combine these controls appropriately?

Comment: @James_D, thanks a million! I merely couldn't know about that.How can I mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: *polite-cough: _I merely couldn't know about that_ you could have read the doc ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, but I have no time at all. I should present this JavaFX app in my University tomorrow:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white part you're seeing is not actually the `ImageView` but is the `StackPane` that's used as a the viewport for the scroll pane.

Referring to the [CSS documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane) you can change the background color using the following in your external CSS file:

```css
.scroll-pane .viewport { 
    -fx-background-color: xxx ; 
}
```

replacing `xxx` with whatever color you need.